# I keep getting cannot find symbol but i have declared it?

Tags: java

I'm not trying to do anything too fancy here really, there is something very simple here that i'm not noticing.

a little premise, this is a simple grade converter, run the driver, enter a double numberGrade(88.7, 90, 67.2, etc) and it will then go to the service and check the statements like this that i will have for grades A-F

```
if (enterGrade >= 90 && enterGrade <= 100)
             grade = 'A';
```

keep getting an error though

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CondTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter your number grade for a letter grade! >");
        Scanner scanObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        Conditionals condObj = new Conditionals();

        int enterGrade = scanObj.nextInt();

        condObj.Conditionals(enterGrade);
    }
}
```

and heres my method in the service class to reference

```
public class Conditionals
{
    public double letterGrade(double enterGrade)
    {
        char grade = 0;

        if (enterGrade >= 90 && enterGrade <= 100)
             grade = 'A';


        return grade;
    }

}
```

After troubleshooting more i thought maybe changing the

```
condObj.conditionals(enterGrade);
```

to

```
double condObj.conditionals(enterGrade);
```

but no luck.

I keep recieving this same error

```
 CondTest.java:18:error: cannot find symbol
                    condObj.conditionals(enterGrade);
```

Comment: You did not import `Conditionals`. What does it do?

Comment: Which part of the line does it point to?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, there just is no method called `conditionals` in your `Conditionals` class - only a method called `letterGrade`. Maybe you should call this one instead?

Change it to

```
  condObj.letterGrade(enterGrade);
```

And: Scanner.nextInt() returns an `int`, do you have a method that accepts an int param?

Comment: Thank you! it compiled, haha silly mistake :) and yes i changed it to nextDouble instead :)

Comment: `int` is implicitly convertible to `double`.